# YouTube API takes minutes now - instead of seconds

Tags: youtube-data-api

I have a Perl script which uses `LWP::UserAgent` to retrieve a YouTube video's information via an HTTPS request. The script normally would take 2-3 seconds to retrieve three separate HTTPS requests. Now, it takes 15-20 minutes.

I wrote a similar script in Python where I use the following:

```
    import google_auth_oauthlib.flow
    import googleapiclient.discovery
    import googleapiclient.errors
```

And this one request is taking 5-7 minutes.

Then - on Thursday night - the Perl script went back to only taking 2-3 seconds. This lasted for a few hours, and now the time is back to taking 15-20 minutes. The script seems to take forever on the HTTPS call - and not during any other time of the script.

If I take the HTTPS URL and put it in a web browser, it takes less than a second.

The script is over 2,000 lines long, so I can't post it here. But, all I am doing is trying to retrieve:

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics&key=$key&id=$video_comments_to_get`,

where `$key` is my authorization key, and `$video_comments_to_get` is the 11 character YouTube video ID value.

This all started after YouTube's outage on November 11th. Any ideas why this would be taking so long? I only run this script 10-15 times a day - so it isn't like I am over my quota.

Comment: Since you experienced no delays within your web browser, I'd recommend to test passing to your instance of `LWP::UserAgent` the HTTP header [`User-Agent`](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent#agent) set to the value of your browser's user agent string.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am already doing that with:

```
$ua2->agent('Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i586; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0');
```

Comment: Now it is working again - it takes about two seconds to do the three HTTPS calls.  Start: Mon Nov 23 12:26:27 2020
  End: Mon Nov 23 12:26:29 2020
Weird.